# Can I create multiple partitions on a microsd using Windows XP or Linux?

Tags: linux, windows

I have a 60GB microSD. Android seems only to be able to recognize 30GB or less. I want to partition the card with multiple partitions and be able to hide/unhide partitions as I see fit.  How might I go about this.  I'll use Windows XP or Linux (whichever distro works).

Answer (score 2):

You can only do this if you can persuade Windows to think of it as a fixed rather than a removable disk. There are instructions on the web but I don't recommend it due to possible compatibility issues.

Not worth messing with removable media like this, it is unreliable enough without hacking it.

Comment: There are a few Flash Drives that can be partitioned - e.g. the one in the link. But I never have seen a SD card that can be partitioned. http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA12K22V7465&cm_re=sandisk_extreme_64gb-_-0BD-000B-000V6-_-Product

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely create partitions without any problem.

I did this many times in Linux. The easiest would be to use [gparted](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) if you have no experience or some other tool like cfdisk.

You only need to make sure the first partition is NTFS or FAT because otherwise Windows will want to format your drive. The second partition can be anything you want.